# Hide tab for user page for specific roles

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to hide tab for user page. This is good script but work only for node type. How can I make it work for user pages?
Thanks to all!

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'article' && in_array('editor', $variables['user']->  roles)) {
        $to_be_removed = array('node/%/edit', 'node/%/view');
        foreach ($variables['tabs'] as $group_key =>$tab_group) {
            if (is_array($tab_group)) {
                foreach ($tab_group as $key =>$tab) {
                    if (isset($tab['#link']['path']) && in_array($tab['#link']['path'], $to_be_removed)) {
                        unset($variables['tabs'][$group_key][$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

/--------
Update
--------/

Now I tryed this:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    /* Hide Tabs in users page */
    global $user;
    $arg = arg();
    if (($arg == 'user') && in_array('gestore', $variables['user']->roles)) {
        foreach ($variables['tabs'] as $group_key =>$tab_group) {
            if (is_array($tab_group)) {
                foreach ($tab_group as $key =>$tab) {
                    if (isset($tab['#link']['path'])) {
                        unset($variables['tabs'][$group_key][$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not work.

/----- Last Update -------/

This works. Thx @Yogesh.

```
global $user;
if ((arg(0) == 'user') && in_array('editor', $variables['user']->roles)) {
    foreach ($variables['tabs'] as $group_key =>$tab_group) {
        if (is_array($tab_group)) {
            foreach ($tab_group as $key =>$tab) {
                if (isset($tab['#link']['path'])) {
                    unset($variables['tabs'][$group_key][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its important to note that the tabs are shown because user role has permission to edit entites, if you are hiding to restrict them from updating then better you change permissions for the user role, but if you are hiding it for UI purpose then its fine.

Comment: @Daniele, you're using `$arg` wrong, `$arg` is an array. You've to check `$arg[0] == 'user'` when checking first argument as user.

Comment: @arpitr sure, it's a change for the theme UI. I want to put a side menu instead of tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7.x) function. The function returns a component of the current Drupal path. i.e. if you're on edit user page, the values returned by arg() function will be arg(0) as 'user', arg(1) as user ID, arg(2) as 'edit'.

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $arg = arg();
  if (('user' == $arg) && (!empty($arg[1]) && is_numeric($arg[1])) && in_array('editor', $variables['user']->roles)) {
    // Your code goes here..
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Where should I put the user's role? In arg(2)?

Comment: No its same like you done before put role in if condition. if (in_array('editor', $variables['user']->  roles)) { //code }

Comment: @Daniele, I've updated code to check user role.

Comment: @Yogesh Last question... if I wanted to set only for authenticated users (without a role)?

Comment: You can simply check `!empty($user->uid);` or use [`user_is_logged_in()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7.x) and if it returned TRUE then user is logged in else not.

Comment: `$user_roles = array_keys($user->roles);
 if(($user->uid) && empty($user_roles)) {...`